# How do I optimise loading a file in python

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following code, which is taking a fair swag of time.  I was wondering if there is a quicker way.

```
for line in lines:
    line=line.rstrip()
    temp = line.split(",")
    splitcsv.append(temp)
```

I've heard that using map and removing 'dots' notation can help, but I'm not sure how they would apply in this instance.

The complete function (if that provides greater insight to what I am trying to achieve is as follows).

```
def get_data(filename):
    """returns a nested list from a csv file, including headings"""
    with open(filename) as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
    splitcsv = []
    for line in lines:
        line=line.rstrip()
        temp = line.split(",")
        splitcsv.append(temp)
    return splitcsv
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

What I have done above works, I just imaging that there are much faster ways of doing things.  I have seen various web pages that suggest using map functions and removing dot notation from python to speed it up, but as I am new to python, I'm struggling to see how to get it to work in this instance.

Comment: why not using `pandas.read_csv`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv library which is optimized for performance and handles edge cases such as fields with commas or newlines.

```
import csv

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        splitcsv = [row for row in reader]
    return splitcsv
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading all lines and then iterating over them, you could try to read and process at the same time without reading all lines into a list before.

```py
def get_data(filename):
    """returns a nested list from a csv file, including headings"""
    with open(filename) as infile:
        return [line.rstrip().split(",") for line in infile]
```

It would be good though if you provided:

- what is the estimated size of input data
- what is the time you achieved (using your implementation) for the input data
- what is the time boundary which shouldn't be exceeded for the input data

Comment: Thanks for that.  That appears to have improved the load time of the file.  I just need to look at some other parts to see what else I can speed up.

Comment: Happy to help. You could upvote/accept the answer if it satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid reading the entire file into memory which may improve matters:

```
def get_data(filename):
    splitcsv = []
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in map(str.rstrip, data):
            splitcsv.append(line.split(','))
    return splitcsv
```

**Performance:**

On my machine I have a CSV file with one million rows each with four columns. This function loads that file into my list in <1.5s